# unresolved external symbol while linking to boost statically

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking

I'm trying to build my application and statically linking it to Boost 1.57 but I get 6 linking errors:

```
>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/static'; ignored
2>ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
2>ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
2>ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPBD0AAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::filesystem::path::path<char const [8]>(char const (&)[8],void *)" (??$?0$$BY07$$CBD@path@filesystem@boost@@QAE@AAY07$$CBDPAX@Z)
2>ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPB_W0AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$codecvt@_WDH@5@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPB_W0AAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
2>ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::filesystem::path & __thiscall boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(class boost::filesystem::path const &)" (??_0path@filesystem@boost@@QAEAAV012@ABV012@@Z) referenced in function "class boost::filesystem::path __cdecl boost::filesystem::operator/(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::filesystem::path const &)" (??Kfilesystem@boost@@YA?AVpath@01@ABV201@0@Z)
2>ShaderProgram.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,int> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@SAABV?$codecvt@_WDH@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::filesystem::path::path<char const [8]>(char const (&)[8],void *)" (??$?0$$BY07$$CBD@path@filesystem@boost@@QAE@AAY07$$CBDPAX@Z)
2>C:\Users\Structo\Desktop\ReStructo\build-release\src\Release\ReStructo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

What I did:

1. I built boost with:

   ```
   b2 link=static variant=release runtime-link=static
   ```
2. In my Cmake, I have

   ```
   set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
   set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-static")
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
   set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
   find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)
   ```
3. In Visual Studio 2013
   I set solution configuration to Release
   Runtime library to Multithreaded
   Set the path to the .libs in VC++ Directories->Library path

Any idea how I could fix this?
Thank you very much for your time!